# How can I vertically center content in a column?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap divs, and I can't get the content of the div to be centered(in height) . I looked at many questions but everything I change fixed one thing and broke another..

Here is a picture of how it looks (I would like the movie details to be centered as well as the admin options) :

[image]

And here relavent code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <hr />
    <h3>@Html.ActionLink(item.MovieName, "GetMovieById", new { Id = item.MovieId }):</h3>
    <br/>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="@Url.Action("GetMovieById/" + item.MovieId, "Movie")">
            <img src="@item.Picture.PictureName" style="width:100%;height:30%; " />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
             <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.Genre.GenreName)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre.GenreName)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                Movie Rating
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @(item.Review.Count() == 0 ? "No reviews yet" : ((double)item.Review.Sum(m => m.ReviewRating) / item.Review.Count()).ToString())
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.MovieDuration) (Min)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MovieDuration)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.YearOfPublish)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.YearOfPublish)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                Writers
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @foreach (var writer in item.Writer)
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink(writer.WriterName, "GetWriterById", "Writer", new { Id = writer.WriterId }, null)
                    if (writer != item.Writer.Last())
                    {
                        <tab>,</tab>
                    }
                }
            </dd>

            <dt>
                Directors
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @foreach (var director in item.Director)
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink(director.DirectorName, "GetDirectorById", "Director", new { Id = director.DirectorId }, null)
                    if (director != item.Director.Last())
                    {
                        <tab>,</tab>
                    }
                }
            </dd>
            <dt>
                Actors
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @foreach (var actor in item.Actor)
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink(actor.ActorName, "GetActorById", "Actor", new { Id = actor.ActorId }, null)
                    if (actor != item.Actor.Last())
                    {
                        <tab>,</tab>
                    }
                }
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" >

        @if (ViewBag.isAdmin == "true")
        {
        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MovieId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Change crew", "ChangeMovieCast", new { id = item.MovieId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.MovieId })
        </p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide us the final HTML and not the template

Comment: A fiddle/working code snippet would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Bootstrap's [flexbox mechanisms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment) on the row element that contains your columns:

```
<row class="align-items-center">
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/knbtf1d6/)**